# Does Hazelcast honor a default cache configuration

Tags: hazelcast, jcache

In the hazelcast documentation there are a few brief references to a cache named "default" - for instance, here:
http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#jcache-declarative-configuration

Later, there is another mention of cache default configuration here:
http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#icache-configuration

What I would like is to be able to configure "default" settings that are inherited when caches are created. For instance, given the following configuration snippet:

```
<cache name="default">
  <statistics-enabled>true</statistics-enabled>
  <management-enabled>true</management-enabled>
  <expiry-policy-factory>
    <timed-expiry-policy-factory expiry-policy-type="ACCESSED" time-unit="MINUTES" duration-amount="2"/>
  </expiry-policy-factory>
</cache>
```

I'd like for the following test to pass:

```
@Test
public void defaultCacheSettingsTest() throws Exception {
  CacheManager cacheManager = underTest.get();
  Cache cache = cacheManager.createCache("foo", new MutableConfiguration<>());
  CompleteConfiguration cacheConfig = (CompleteConfiguration) cache.getConfiguration(CompleteConfiguration.class);
  assertThat(cacheConfig.isManagementEnabled(), is(true));
  assertThat(cacheConfig.isStatisticsEnabled(), is(true));
  assertThat(cacheConfig.getExpiryPolicyFactory(),
    is(AccessedExpiryPolicy.factoryOf(new Duration(TimeUnit.MINUTES, 2l)))
  );
}
```

Ehcache has a "templating" mechanism and I am hoping that I can get a similar behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hazelcast supports [configuration with wildcards](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8/manual/html-single/index.html#using-wildcards). You can use `<cache name="*">` for all `Cache`s to share the same configuration, or apply other patterns to group `Cache` configurations as you wish.

Note that since you already use Hazelcast declarative configuration to configure your `Cache`s, you should use `CacheManager.getCache` instead of `createCache` to obtain the `Cache` instance: `Cache`s created with `CacheManager.createCache(..., Configuration)` disregard the declarative configuration since they are configured explicitly with the `Configuration` passed as argument.